# Did I make a mistake or is the question wrong? How do I calculate the magnitude $r'(t)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

[image]

I took the derivative of each term, then added their squares together and took the square root. I get $$\sqrt{t^2 + 6t + 10}$$ which is very close to choice A but it's off by 1 underneath the square root. If it was $\sqrt{t^2 + 6t + 9}$ then it would be the same as $|t+3|$, but it's not.

Did I make a mistake, or is the question wrong?

Comment: Wolfram confirms that what you did is fine.

Comment: I agree with your result.

Comment: OK. thank you - then it means the question is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

Since $$r'(t)=<\cos (t)-t\sin(t), \sin(t)+t\cos(t),(6t+9)^{\frac{1}{2}}>$$

We have that $$|r'(t)|=\sqrt{(\cos (t)-t\sin(t))^2+(\sin(t)+t\cos(t))^2+6t+9}$$
$$=\sqrt{(\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t))(t^2+1)+6t+9}$$
$$=\sqrt{t^2+6t+10}$$

In part $D)$, they've added the $2t\cos(t)\sin(t)$ terms instead of subtracting.